# Can anyone expolain this? Cell culture vials have strange hair-like condensation patterns

Tags: lab-techniques, cell-culture, tissue, bioinorganic-chemistry

What is the hair-like polymer that condenses on the caps of the plastic cell vial? Inside vial are cells in a mixture of FBS and DMSO. The vials were frozen slowly in a special isopropanol-filled container (isopropanol does not touch the vials) to -80 degrees celsius, then put on dry-ice to move to a liquid nitrogen cryogenic freezer. The hair-like crystals appear to be water, but bend toward my finger when nearby, similar to the static attraction.

I suspect the has something to do with DMSO/isopropanol leaking out, and the very low temperatures cause this strange condensation pattern, but I'm not sure. 
[image: strange condensation]

Comment: This question might be better suited for the Chemistry or Physics SE